# Returning data within a date range in Snowflake gives error

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datediff

I am using the strings below in Snowflake, as I have previously used in SQL Server, to get a date range and I am getting this error

> SQL compilation error: error line 3 at position 48  Invalid argument
> types for function 'DATE_DIFFTIMESTAMPINMONTHS': (NUMBER(1,0),
> TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9))

What I want to achieve is to get the date from 31/05/2022 to 01/05/2022 in column
"assign Date (Local time)" from "YML"."SYNCASSIGN"."uio_faster_daily" table in Snowflake.

I agree the syntax in Snowflake might be slightly different from SQL Server, but I feel it just requires a small adjustment which I am also trying.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "YML"."SYNCASSIGN"."uio_faster_daily"
where "assign Date (Local time)" >=DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate())-1, 0) 
and
"assign Date (Local time)" < DATEADD(mm, 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate())-1, 0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say I didn't test it properly, but you should be able to get the beginning of the previous month with the following expression:

```
select DATE_TRUNC('month', DATEADD(month, -1 , getdate()))::DATE ;
```

The following should give you the last day of the previous month:

```
select LAST_DAY(DATEADD(month, -1 , getdate())) ;
```

So you should be able to write your query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM "YML"."SYNCASSIGN"."uio_faster_daily"
where "assign Date (Local time)" >= DATE_TRUNC('month', DATEADD(month, -1 , getdate()))::DATE
and
"assign Date (Local time)" < LAST_DAY(DATEADD(month, -1 , getdate()));
```

If you want to include the last day, the last filter should be "<=" instead of "<".

Updated:

```
SELECT *
FROM "YML"."SYNCASSIGN"."uio_faster_daily"
where "assign Date (Local time)" >= DATE_TRUNC('month', DATEADD(month, -1 , getdate()))::DATE
and
"assign Date (Local time)" < DATE_TRUNC('month', current_date())::DATE;
```

Comment: quite close but with <= and < the last filter returns the second to the last day of the month

Comment: When you run the query today, what should you expect to return from "DATEADD(mm, 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate())-1, 0))" ?

Comment: it give me the same data as the previous day which is 31/05/2022 as the last day of the month.

Comment: @Metacoder sorry I don't understand the issue. The expressions return 2022-05-01 and 2022-05-31. And 31/05/2022 is the last day of the previous month. So where is the problem?

Comment: "assign Date (Local time)" < LAST_DAY(DATEADD(month, -1 , getdate())); "   returns 30/05/2022 instead of 31/05/2022. sorry for being a pain

Comment: select LAST_DAY(DATEADD(month, -1 , getdate())); <-- what does this one return?

Comment: same result 30/05/2022

Comment: @Metacoder Are you sure that you run the query I shared? select LAST_DAY(DATEADD(month, -1 , getdate())); <-- this is a stand-alone query.

Comment: apologies I used it in the queries 2022-05-31

Comment: @Metacoder I updated the answer because I think your column is timestamp

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last day of a month using the LAST_DAY function.

You can get the first day of the month using this:

```
date_trunc('month', current_date())
```

If you need to get a date in the previous month (compared to the current date) to plug into these two functions then you can use:

```
add_months(current_date(), -1)
```

Comment: "assign Date (Local time)"  is a column with lots of dates. what we need is is to have the dates for the previous month i.e. May returned from 01/05/2022 to 31/05/2022 and not an individual date that is why we are using                                                                        
where "assign Date (Local time)" >=DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate())-1, 0) 
and
"assign Date (Local time)" < DATEADD(mm, 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate())-1, 0))```

Comment: Apologies - I thought that getting the month was pretty straightforward but I've updated my answer to include that piece of code as well

Comment: no worries. what I am looking for is a date range between a period. but I appreciate your help. @NickW